# Calculating the random food position in a snake game in C language

Tags: c

I have problem understanding why does it have to calculate the food position like this:

```
foodSite.x = (rand()%23*2+1)+2;
foodSite.y = rand()%17+2;
```

The boarder size in the game is 50*19.

I've tried to change the code to rand()%49+1 and rand()%18+1, but then the game won't work.  The food won't be eaten by the snake.  It just stays in the same position.

Comment: we would need more information about the code to determien what is going on

Comment: Please read [ask], edit question,

Comment: The full code is on this website http://rosymoggy.blogspot.tw/2014/01/c.html#comment-form.  But I can't copy the full code here.

Comment: @HannahChen Show us the relevant code here.

Comment: Have a look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). `%` takes precedence over `+` and may be leading to unexpected results on your end. If that is your code, you should also have a look at [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: See online for how the operators work. Then write down all possible values and then check the source code. Please understand this no tutorial or "explain the codez" site.

Answer (score 1):

- Given

  ```
  foodSite.x = (rand()%23*2+1)+2;
  foodSite.y = rand()%17+2;
  ```

  the domains for `x` and `y` are `[3, 47]` and `[2, 18]` respectively.
- Instead, given

  ```
  foodSite.x = rand()%49+1;
  foodSite.y = rand()%18+1;
  ```

  the domains for `x` and `y` are `[1, 49]` and `[1, 18]` respectively.

Therefore, the two expressions do not correspond to equivalent domains.

As for the reason why the game doesn't work, it is likely that the **food** is not supposed to be placed in some locations and this was just *hard-coded* in some way.

Comment: Good answer, though `x` can only be odd, not even. But I think OP wants to understand why are coordinates being calculated like this, what these fields do represent. Anyway this is not the place for such a question and his question lacks information, so . . . . . .

Comment: @qreon thanks for pointing it out, it slipped my mind :)

Comment: I think I kinda figure it out.  I just alter the printWall function and found out that the space between x coordinate is half of the space between the y coordinate.  That's why the board is a square not a rectangle.
So, probably this is the reason why 23 has to times 2.  I just tried foodSite.x=rand()%23*2+1, and it worked fine. ( This is just my guess.)
I know this is not a good question to ask here, but I've searched for tons of information.  I just couldn't figure out.  Really sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah that was a likely cause.